# Laravel - Viewing data from other table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In the database, there are a `packages` and a `features` tables. Each package have a few features.

What is a good solution to add features into `packages` variable or how it should be done in Laravel?

```
   public function Phone()
    {
            $packages = Packages::getPackages('phone')->get();

            foreach($packages as $package) {
                    // How to add Features into packge?
                    PackagesFeatures::where('packages_id', '=', $package->id)->get();
            }

            return View::make('phone')->with('packages', $packages);
    }
```

In the browser, I expect to view something like this:

```
<h2>PackageName 1 </h2>
- Feature Name 1
- Feature Name 2

<h2>PackageName 2 </h2>
- Feature Name 5
- Feature Name 7
```

Comment: setup relations and use eager loading when you fetch the packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what does getPackages('phone') is returning but you can use [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) if you relation ([One to Many](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many) ) is correct which is as follows.

```
    $packages = Packages::with('features')->get();
```

In the above statement the features will be method in Package Model class.

**Package Model**

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PageFeatures','page_id');
}
```

Now you can pass the packages model to the view.

**View**

```
@foreach($packages as $package)
    <h2>Package Name </h2>
    @foreach($package->features as $features)
        <li> Fetch feature name </li>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Make sure you check out the docs links.

Comment: Thank you getPackages() is this `public static function getPackages($service) { return Packages::where('service', '=', $service); }`

Comment: `with('features')` does this mean `features()` in a Model?

Comment: Yes, it will look for features method in the Package Model.